# Are there any free .NET SFTP server (not client) libraries?

Tags: .net, sftp

How can I do an integration test of our software's SFTP client functionality (e.g. connecting to an SFTP server, validating the fingerprint, gracefully failing upon invalid password or wrong port, uploading a file)?

What I have tried so far is to use a free .NET SFTP server library to setup a temporary SFTP server in the test and then direct our software to that server. Here's an example test:

```
[Test]
public void FileUploadedToSFTPServer()
{
    var rsaKey = Nuane.Net.SshKey.Generate(Nuane.Net.SshKeyAlgorithm.RSA, 1024);
    var ip = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 2 });
    var port = 23456;
    var login = "test";
    var password = "someTestPassword";
    var userDir = Path.GetTempPath() + @"SFTPData";

    if (!Directory.Exists(userDir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(userDir);
    }

    var sftpServer = new Nuane.Net.SftpServer();
    sftpServer.Keys.Add(rsaKey);
    sftpServer.Bindings.Add(ip, port);
    sftpServer.Users.Add(new Nuane.Net.SshUser(login, password, userDir));

    sftpServer.Start();

    RunClientSoftware(rsaKey.Fingerprint, ip, port, login, password);
    FileAssert.Exists(new FileInfo(userDir + "/data.dat"), "The data.dat file was not uploaded to the SFTP server.");

    sftpServer.Stop();
}
```

The library I tried using is the [Nuane.Net.SftpServer](https://nuane.com/sftp-lite/) library, but it has a bug where the Stop method on the SftpServer doesn't actually close the socket that is listening for new client connections. That bug causes problems when I try to run multiple tests, since new instances try to open the same port that is already being listened on, and then that fails the test prematurely. Since that library doesn't offer the source code, I can't even attempt to fix it.

I feel like this strategy would work if I could find a library that didn't have that bug. Is there a free .NET library that can be used to setup an SFTP server for some basic testing like what I was attempting? Or is there another testing option that I should use (one that preferably doesn't involve extensive re-writes of the existing client code to accommodate the test)?

Comment: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library

Comment: @ColinM, I need a server, not a client. The WinSCP page you linked to is for a client library.

Comment: I apologize, I skipped a very fundamental requirement. Have you considered hand-rolling your own code, or using something like WinSCP to host the server? Any particular reason why you want to write an SFTP server? Here's a server link I've found from briefly looking online - https://www.rebex.net/file-server/

Comment: As far as I know, WinSCP is only a client, not a server. I don't want to write an SFTP server. I want to write tests that verify that our software has connected to an SFTP server and uploaded files to it. Also, the Rebex library would be ideal but there is one problem: it is not free.

Comment: So you want to mock out an SFTP server for the purpose of testing, like integration testing. You could host with OpenSSH and publish a test, or staging version of your application which points to your test SFTP which you can then use a test harness to run end to end tests - your harness can contain C# tests written in unit style, with a test runner console executing the tests.

Comment: @ColinM, yes that could be done, but it adds complications (tests would no depend upon a new process/server whereas they could be run on any machine independently before). I would prefer my original plan if possible. If there aren't any free .NET SFTP server libraries, I might have to do what you've described.

Comment: You don't need to test that the file has actually been uploaded, because you're not just testing your service - that's when you begin testing the functionality of an SFTP server. If you want to run an in-memory service then you could hand-roll code which accepts a connection and takes some input (I.E: uploading a file) and then confirm that your service behaves as expected in happy path and negative scenarios.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173096/discussion-between-anssssss-and-colinm).

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that lets me keep using the Nuane.Net.SftpServer library for now.

```
//sftpServer.Stop(); //this doesn't work
sftpServer.Bindings.Clear(); //this does cause the listening socket to be closed
```

I still would be interested in any answers that could point me to another free, .NET, SFTP server library that I could use for testing.